# System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled

Tags: android, networking, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I am Testing App in my Real device. I am getting Task Cancelled exception when am i running this code in my home wifi network but in my office network it is working file why ?

```
string API = "http://192.168.0.5/api/test/LoginCheck?username=" + Username.Text + "&password=" + Password.Text + "";
                        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();                            
                        string dataResult = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(API);
```

Comment: The IP, is the same in your work and your house?

Comment: Not the same network both are different.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, the petition it's losing in your home network, try to change to the current ip

Comment: i think it is ip problem but i dont know what to do. i dont have any knowledge about router. i got network connection recently in my home.

Comment: Where is this api hosted? I'm guessing it is running on your machine? That IP is the address of the machine running the api... So you need to find that. On Windows you can do that by starting the command prompt and using `ipconfig` or from the terminal on Mac using `ifconfig`. That output will have your machine's IP address on the current subnet.

Comment: yes it is running in my machine only

Comment: That IP Address is my local system ip address only

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a space between 'http://' and your IP. Besides this, like @Chefes said you have to check if this address exists in your home network.

Comment: there is no space. that is posting mistake